# ASP.NET MVC RazorPDF save/download from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Good time of day. I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 & RazorPDF for print my View page in PDF
For example:

```
    // GET: /Razorpdf/Pdf/
    public ActionResult Pdf()
    {
        var model = repository.GetStudents().ToList();

        return new RazorPDF.PdfResult(model, "PDF");
    }
```

It's print what I need exactly, but I don't understand what is the best approach to save/download my Pdf() into/from database (I'm use SQL Server 2012) in the binding to my student. Have any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can use blob to save any binary data in the db, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'll probably save the file on the filesystem or some external storage if you are using one and then just use the link to the file for downloads. I think it'd be much easier and faster this way, since you don't need to do anything else for the download and your server can serve the pdf without your app doing anything. Also easier to implement caching, especially with unique names (e.g GUID). You just need a string field in the db to store the file name/path.

Comment: Now that I read your question again I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the generated PDF instead to just show it as a view then you can do this by following code just before you return the PDFResult as view.

This is the code

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=EmployeeResume.pdf");
```